# Raphael minify version doesn't work on IE. Any idea?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, raphael, minify

I've an issue with the fantastic RaphaelJs lib. It doesn't work on IE (8 and 7) if I use the minify version. It works of with the dev version.

An error is raised on `paper = Raphael("canvas", 100, 100);`

Any idea what can be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed : https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/158